# Show that $\sqrt{1+t}$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2][\![t]\!]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is an interesting (I thought) question:

> Show that $\sqrt{1+t}$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2][\![t]\!]$

That is, let $f(t)=\sum_{k \ge 0} a_k t^k \in \mathbb{Q}[\![t]\!]$ be the unique power series with $f(t)^2=1+t$ and $f(0)=1$, and show that each $a_k$ is of the form $b/2^m$ for $b,m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Naively I just want to "compare coefficients". That is

$$\begin{align}
f(t)^2 &= (a_0+a_1t+a_2 t^2 + \cdots)(a_0+a_1t+a_2 t^2 + \cdots) \\
     &= a_0^2 + (2a_0 a_1)t + \cdots \\
     &= 1 + t
\end{align}$$

Thus given knowledge of $a_k$ it should, in principle, be possible to determine $a_{k+1}$ via $\sum_{i+j=k+1}a_i a_j=0$, but this didn't seem to work out that well.

In fact the question tells you (one method) to do it - show that $a_k = b_{k-1} + b_k$ where $b_k = \binom{2k}{k}/(-4)^k$. I'm not quite sure how I should do that. Induction seems to be the obvious approach. Recalling that $\sum_{i+j=k+1}a_i a_j=0$ one then inductively knows all terms apart from $a_{k+1}$, but I couldn't figure out how to manipulate the $b_k$'s appropriately.

Can anyone offer any hints?

Furthermore - can one extend this method to show that $(1+t)^{1/n}$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}[1/n][\![t]\!]$?

Comment: Just a comment, not a criticism of your question, but: $\sqrt{1+t}$ is a mathematical expression in $t$, well-defined and universally understood for real $t\geq-1$. And there is indeed a power series in $t$ that converges to the value of $\sqrt{1+t}$ when $t$ is in $(-1,1)$. But that's not the same as equaling $\sqrt{1+t}$. I just say this because sometimes understanding better what a power series really is can help solve problems in front of you. The full object $\sqrt{1+t}$ cannot be "put into" $\mathbb{Z}[1/2][[t]]$; a restriction of it can.

Answer (score 13):

The power series for $(1+t)^{1/n}$ is $\sum_{k \geq 0} \binom{1/n}{k}t^k$, where $\binom{a}{k} = \frac{a(a-1)\cdots(a-k+1)}{k!}$ for any $a$ (not just positive integers). If $a$ is rational then $\binom{a}{k}$ is rational. Your initial question is now: why is $\binom{1/2}{k}$ a fraction with 2-power denominator?

I claim that for any rational number $a$, the only primes that could possibly appear in the denominator of $\binom{a}{k}$ are primes that appear in the denominator of $a$. (Take $a = 1/2$ to see this answers your question.) For instance, $\binom{1/3}{k}$ will have 3-power denominators, which you can visibly see happening if you look at the power series for $(1+t)^{1/3}$:
$$
(1+t)^{1/3} = 1 + \frac{1}{3}t - \frac{1}{9}t^2 + \frac{5}{81}t^3 - \frac{10}{243}t^4 + \cdots.
$$
The claim tells us that the denominators of coefficients of $(1+t)^{1/6}$ are products of powers of 2 and 3, so the fraction can always be written to have a denominator that is a power of 6:
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+t)^{1/6} & = & 1 + \frac{1}{6}t - \frac{5}{2^3\cdot 3^2}t^2 + \frac{55}{2^4\cdot 3^4}t^3 - \frac{935}{2^7\cdot 3^5}t^4 + \cdots \\
& = & 1 + \frac{1}{6}t - \frac{15}{6^3}t^2 + \frac{55}{6^4}t^3 - \frac{8415}{6^7}t^4 + \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
This answers your "Furthermore..." question in the affirmative.

To prove the claim made above, we'll prove the contrapositive: if $p$ does *not* appear in the denominator of $a$ then $p$ does not appear in the denominator of $\binom{a}{k}$. The main idea to be used here is $p$-adic limits and continuity. Since $a$ has no $p$ in its denominator, it is a $p$-adic integer and thus $a$ is a $p$-adic limit of a sequence of positive integers $\{b_i\}$ (e.g., use as that sequence $\{b_i\}$ the truncations of the $p$-adic expansion of $a$ in the $p$-adic integers).  The polynomial function $\binom{x}{k} \in {\mathbf Q}[x]$ is continuous in the $p$-adic topology, so from $a = \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} b_i$ we get $\binom{a}{k} = \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} \binom{b_i}{k}$. Since $b_i$ is a positive integer, $\binom{b_i}{k}$ is an integer. Therefore $\binom{a}{k}$ is a $p$-adic limit of integers, which means $\binom{a}{k}$ is a $p$-adic integer, i.e., $|\binom{a}{k}|_p \leq 1$, and that's another way of saying there is no $p$ in the denominator of the fraction $\binom{a}{k}$.

Comment: **Remark** $\:$ The claim can also be [proved very simply](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192/242) (high-school level)

Comment: @Bill: would you consider posting an answer that illustrates your other method to show the denominator of $\binom{7/10}{17}$ is not divisible by 3?

Comment: @KCd - thanks, this is really cool - much more than I was expecting!

Answer (score 8):

I had to solve (something similar to) this for a homework assignment this past semester, so I'll post a little about how I solved it.

Suppose we have some $f=a_0+a_1t+\cdots$ such that $f^2=1+t$. Then we have the infinitely many equations
\begin{align}
a_0^2 &= 1\\
2a_0a_1&=1\\
a_0a_2+a_1a_1+a_2a_0&=0\\
a_0a_3+a_1a_2+a_2a_1+a_3a_0&=0\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{i=0}^{j}a_ia_{j-i} &= 0\\
\vdots
\end{align}

Obvious choices for $a_0$ and $a_1$ are 1 and 1/2. As you mentioned in your original post, knowing $a_i$ for $i=0,1\dots,n$ gives you knowledge of $a_{n+1}$, so (starting over) defining $a_0=1,\,a_1=1/2,$ and
$$
a_n=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_ka_{n-k}
$$
(which is just the $(n+1)$th equation above solved for $a_n$) sets you up for an easy inductive proof that $f^2=t+1$.

Comment: And clearly this also shows that $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: From the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) we get
$$
\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac t2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k-3)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2k)}t^k.
$$

Your question asks you to prove that all the coefficients are of the form $a(1/2)^\ell$ for some integers $a,\ell$. This is not too difficult, but not entirely obvious. So my hint is: First replace $t$ with $4t$ above (i.e. looking at the series of $\sqrt{1+4t}$ instead). It turns out that then the coefficients become integers. That is not obvious either, but looking for information about *Catalan numbers* should get you going. But why does that solve your problem?

Comment: It seems to me that the hint that came with the problem is closely related to [a proof of integrality of Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: ... and I'm fairly sure the Bill Dubuque has posted a link to a relevant series in one of his relatively recent answers. I'm afraid I cannot find it now.

Comment: Found [it](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/124378/11619)!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Calculate the Taylor series for $\sqrt{1+t}$, centered at $t=0$.

Comment: Dear Joe - thank you for the answer. I should have been clearer that I am aware one can just explicitly work out the coefficients using Taylor series - I was more interested in finding out how to see where the recurrence for the $a_k$'s will come from