# How to extract roots in a complete local ring using binomial series

Tags: commutative-algebra, roots

Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m$ that is $m$-adically complete, and assume $1/2 \in A^\times$.  I've read in several places that for any $x \in m$, a square root of $1 + x$ in $A$ is given by the binomial series

$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty {{1/2} \choose n} x^n,
$$
where ${{1/2} \choose n} = \frac{(1/2)(1/2 - 1) \cdots (1/2 - n + 1)}{n!}$.  I don't understand why these binomial coefficients make sense in $A$.  We have $n!$ in the denominator, so why is $n! \in A^\times$?

Comment: A ratio being in $A$ does *not* require that the denominator has to be a unit. For example, 15/5 is an integer even though 5 is not a unit in the integers. Or, to give an example with a local ring, 15/5 is in ${\mathbf Z}_5$ (the 5-adic integers) even though 5 is not a unit in ${\mathbf Z}_5$. The point is that the rational number $\binom{1/2}{n}$ in reduced form has a denominator that is a power of 2, so it makes sense in $A$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/show-that-sqrt1t-lies-in-mathbbz1-2-t.

Comment: Ah yes, I see.  Thanks!

Comment: @KCd Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: Julian: You could post my comment as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As [KCd remarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138532/how-to-extract-roots-in-a-complete-local-ring-using-binomial-series#comment318861_138532):

> A ratio being in $A$ does not require that the denominator has to be a unit. For example, $15/5$ is an integer even though $5$ is not a unit in the integers. Or, to give an example with a local ring, $15/5$ is in $\Bbb Z_5$ (the $5$-adic integers) even though $5$ is not a unit in $\Bbb Z_5$. The point is that the rational number $1/2 \choose n$ in reduced form has a denominator that is a power of $2$, so it makes sense in $A$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/show-that-sqrt1t-lies-in-mathbbz1-2-t) for details.