# Use of $p$-adic numbers in generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, p-adic-number-theory

Generating functions are very useful tool to solve various counting problems. One way in which this is done, is to evaluate the generating function at complex values (see e.g. [this video of 3b1b](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric)). Are there cases where one can evaluate a generating function at $p$-adic numbers to gain information about a combinatorial problem?

PS: there is famously a $p$-adic analogue of the Riemann zeta function, but I'm looking at simpler instances.

Comment: For that specific problem we could have used any one of the infinitely many p-adic fields where $p=1 \mod 5$, as they contain a fifth root of unity to carry out that argument. We could still extend the other p-adic fields too, but if we're going to talk about extensions, we could boil it down a bit further to $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ with $\zeta$ a 5th root of unity, and not really bring in any real/complex or p-adic fields into it in the first place. To make use of p-adics we'd need to bring in some limits somewhere, like dealing with asymptotics of an infinite series for a generating function.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in the question: i meant, use the $p$-adic in a way that the complex number could not be used. Could you explicit your example with asymptotics?

Comment: Based on your previous comment, it seems your question has now drifted away from the 3b1b generating function argument (which uses no analysis at all) to ask how $p$-adic numbers can be used to do something that doesn't seem feasible with complex numbers. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951500/classical-number-theoretic-applications-of-the-p-adic-numbers or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873147/finding-non-negative-integers-m-such-that-1-sqrt-2m-has-real-part

Comment: An answer to the question on the page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103565/orbits-of-the-projective-special-linear-group-on-mathbfq-cup-infty gives an application that uses all completions of $\mathbf Q$ to show that when ${\rm PSL}_2(\mathbf Q)$ acts on ${\mathbf P}^1(\mathbf Q)$ by linear fractional transformations, no element of ${\rm PSL}_2(\mathbf Q)$ acts with finitely many orbits. In the proof, you sometimes think about ${\mathbf P}^1(\mathbf Q)$ lying in ${\mathbf P}^1(\mathbf R)$ and sometimes think about it lying in ${\mathbf P}^1(\mathbf Q_p)$ for some prime number $p$.

Comment: @KCd many thanks for all the links, but I did not want the question to "drift" in any way. 3b1b ends his video by saying that complex numbers are so useful because by using a larger input set (the complex number rather than just, say, the rationals) one gets more information. The motivation for the question is: what information could you get if you used the $p$-adics rather than the complex numbers?

Comment: In my second link a sequence $a_m$ is interpolated from being a function of an integer index $m$ to a $p$-adic integer index, which lets you use $p$-adic analysis to determine all positions in the sequence where $a_m$ is $\pm 1$.

Comment: @KCd thanks, this is really cool!

Comment: Have you heard of what a [Bell series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_series) is?

Comment: @TravorLZH a long time ago, I did :)  Could you be so kind as to remind how the p-adics can be put to good use in this context?

Comment: @Merosity I don't mean to be rude in insisting, but I would be really interested in your example with the aymptotics...

Answer (score 1):

I remember having answered this kind of questions on MathOverflow.

One example is that the partial sums $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n\frac{2^i}i$ have $2$-adic valuations tending to infinity. This is proved by evaluating $\log(1 - x) = -\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{x^i}i$ at $x = 2 \in \Bbb Q_2$, which gives $\log(-1) = \frac12\log1 = 0$.

More interestingly the dilogarithm $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i^2}$ also evaluates to $0$ at $x = 2 \in \Bbb Q_2$.