# Factoring over ring of power series

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would we factor $6+x$ over $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, the ring of formal power series with integer coefficients? Proving things are prime is easy, but factoring a nonprime is difficult. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried undetermined coefficients? Of course, the answers are very non-unique.

Comment: Bill Dubuque gave a nice example once in a related problem of factoring in $\Bbb{Z}[[x]]$. Gimme a minute. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/124378/11619)!

Comment: Yes, it factors as a special case of the Catalan factorization that I described [there,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/124378/242) so it is a duplicate of that question.