# What is the definition of Bezout coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

In my past exam I was asked to explain what Bezout coefficients are and what we can use them for. But I can't find any definitions online that answer the question specifically.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_identity.

Comment: Google "bezout" and look at the Wikipedia article. If this is not what you are looking for, you might want to give a little bit more context for us to find out what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bezout GCD identity is $\ \gcd(a,b) = a x + b y\ $ for some integers $\,x,y,\,$ i.e. the gcd can be written as an integral linear combination of its arguments. Here $\,x,y\,$ are the Bezout coefficients.

One common application of Bezout coefficients is computing modular inverses

$$ \gcd(a,b)= 1\,\Rightarrow\, ax+by = 1\,\Rightarrow\,\bmod b\!:\,\ ax\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{-1}\equiv x$$

Here are some other interesting related applications.

- [Hermite's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68540/242) of integrating rational functions.
- [Factoring $\ ab + x\ $ into power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124378/242) when $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1$

By Bezout's GCD identity we may write $\ \color{#c00}{\bf 1} = ad\!-\!bc\,$

Recall the [Catalan series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Proof_of_the_formula) $\rm\, C(x)\in \mathbb Z[[x]]\,$ satisfies $\,\color{#090}{C(x) - x\:C(x)^2\! = 1},\,$ so with $\,e = cd$

$\ \ \   (a - cx\:C(ex))\:(b+dt\:C(ex))\ =\ ab + \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\cdot x\:(\color{#090}{C(ex) - et\:C(ex)^2})\: =\ ab + x$